# Why can't I access my private variable inside a function in PHP?

Tags: php

This returns NULL. It, however, returns the expected value when dumped inside construct.

```
public static $time;

        function __construct()
        {
            $time = $this->getTracker();
        }

        public function stream()
        {
        dd(static::$time);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I really looked hard for this one before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign the variable you have to use `static::$time`:

```
function __construct()
{
    static::$time = $this->getTracker();
}
```

Otherwise you're assigning to a local variable, not the class property.

In general, PHP never lets you use normal variable notation for class properties. You always have to use `class::$variable` for static properties or `$object->variable` for per-object properties.

Answer (score -1):

is that a class and the `class` keyword has been ommitted in the post or did you actually forget it?

```
class myObject {

    public static $time;

    function __construct()
    {
        self::$time = $this->getTracker();
    }

    public function stream()
    {
        dd(self::$time);
    }

}
```

**furthermore, reference to a static var or method is `<objectname>::<varname>` or `self::<varname>` within the objects context. What you did, is creating a local var $time in the constructor.**

Comment: I didn't paste the full snippet, it's there.